# TSQL to count occurrences in a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, count

I have data that has a row for each job change for an employee, is there a way to count the unique jobs changez a person has had like below without using sub queries?

```
name  job
tim   accountant
tim   electrician
tim   accountant
joy   boss
joy   boss
rob   sales
rob   mechanic
rob   teacher
rob   marketing


name  job           jobcount
tim   accountant    3
tim   electrician   3
tim   accountant    3
joy   boss          1
joy   boss          1
rob   sales         4
rob   mechanic      4
rob   teacher       4
rob   marketing     4
```

Comment: Have you considering using `COUNT`? Specifically a windowed one? What did you try and why didn't it work?

Comment: not sure what you mean "windowed"? what is that

Comment: Using the [`OVER` Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I think your jobcount for Tim should be 2 not 3. And given that you want to do a distinct count of jobs I don't see how you would do that without a subquery.  The COUNT function within a window does not allow distinct.

Comment: Hi JMabee ideally I would count the job changes

Comment: What is a _unique_ "jobs changez"? If I go from sales → boss → teacher → boss is that three changes because sales → boss is not the same transition as teacher → boss? Since tim has only had two job changes and two different jobs, how does he rate a `3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case you want to consider a subquery here is how I would do it:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp(name varchar(10),  job varchar(20))
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES
('tim','accountant'),
('tim','electrician'),
('tim','accountant'),
('joy','boss'),
('joy','boss'),
('rob','sales'),
('rob','mechanic'),
('rob','teacher'),
('rob','marketing')

SELECT Name,Job,SUM(JobGrp) OVER(PARTITION BY Name) JobCnt
FROM
(
    select Name,Job, CASE WHEN 1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name,Job ORDER BY Job) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END JobGrp
    from #tmp
) t
```

Comment: that is it thanks Jmabee I will start there :)